# Cassandra relationship between number of queries and size of queries?

Tags: cassandra, query-optimization

I have a problem where we are sending large dataframes of data, the sizes are in the region of 80mb which introduces waiting for the user. The problem is that we are getting information in case the user wants to drill down on certain data points.

In this discussion: [When optimizing database queries, what exactly is the relationship between number of queries and size of queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046902/when-optimizing-database-queries-what-exactly-is-the-relationship-between-numbe)

The author requested a rule of thumb for when you should stop getting all the data and instead increase the amount of queries. I was wondering if similar rules of thumb exist in Cassandra, in order to make sure we scale well?

Answer (score 0):

With Cassandra, the general guidance is to query by partition key.

In addition, many small queries are generally preferable to one large query.  If querying from an application, it’s best to play around with a “max number of threads” and only process that many async query threads at a time, until complete.